# splitting characters using function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I tried to write function like this in PostgreSQL but I'm getting error like

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "elems"
> LINE 22:    RETURN elems;

I want get output like

input: `we@@@ty;rer@@2hjjj`
output:

```
we@@@ty 
rer@@2hjjj
```

please help me to solve this error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_split(
    inputstr text,
    delimeter text)
    RETURNS text[]
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
   delimeter text;  
    elems text[];
    var text;
arr_len int;
  BEGIN
SELECT unnest(string_to_array(inputstr,delimeter))
INTO elems

   RETURN elems;
  END
$BODY$;
```

Comment: If the output should be `123  345` then it seems you are looking for a simple `replace(inputstr, delimiter, '')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_split(
    inputstr text,
    delimeter text)
    RETURNS text[]
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER 

AS $BODY$
DECLARE 
 elems text[];
BEGIN 
 SELECT string_to_array(inputstr,delimeter) INTO elems;
 RETURN elems;
END; 
$BODY$;
```

**Now call this function like this**

```
SELECT UNNEST(fn_split('1,2,3',',')) as retval
```

[image]

**Above is the screenshot which includes function definition and in the first list the command to call this function**

Here is the command that you need to execute in order to call this function in the PostgreSQL query window after the creation of the function.

[image]

Comment: i tried this but not working

Comment: @KSMNOPk you also have 2 declarations of delimeter text; remove the declaration one after DECLARE

Comment: ERROR:  column "inputstr" does not exist
LINE 1: select unnest(string_to_array(inputstr,delimeter))

Comment: I changed my answer with the working function code.

Comment: Call this function like this SELECT UNNEST(fn_split('1,2,3',',')) as retval

Comment: @KSMNOPk You need to change the way of calling function. Check the updated answer about calling fn_split().

Comment: sir this is not working i tried like this return (SELECT UNNEST(fn_split(inputstr,delimeter)) );

Comment: @KSMNOPk No not like this. SELECT UNNEST(fn_split('1,2,3',',')) as retval this line is the way of calling the function fn_split() you don't add this line inside the function

Comment: Sir i want answer in separate rows like if i gave input as "WW@RR;AA@RR" output should be in WW@RR this in one row ;AA@RR this should be in another row

Comment: @KSMNOPk check the screenshot in answer to get an idea how I am doing this

Answer (score 0):

Your function is defined to return an array, however `unnest` would turn the result of creating the array into rows of strings. There is also no need to duplicate the parameter definition as local variables in a DECLARE block. And as you don't seem to want to manipulate the created array somehow, there is no need to store it in a local variable.

It seems you just want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_split(
    inputstr text,
    delimeter text)
    RETURNS text[]
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    immutable
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
   return string_to_array(inputstr,delimeter);
END
$BODY$;
```

Or simpler as a SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_split(
    inputstr text,
    delimeter text)
    RETURNS text[]
    LANGUAGE sql
    immutable
AS 
$BODY$
 select string_to_array(inputstr,delimeter);
$BODY$;
```

Note that the language name is an identifier and should not be enclosed in single quotes. This syntax is deprecated and support for it will be removed in a future Postgres version.

---

Edit:

It seems you don't actually want an array, but one row per element after splitting the input value. In that case the function should be declared as `returns table()` not `returns text[]`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_split(
    inputstr text,
    delimeter text)
    RETURNS table(element text)
    LANGUAGE sql
    immutable
AS 
$BODY$
 select unnest(string_to_array(inputstr,delimeter));
$BODY$;
```

Then use it like this:

```
select *
from fn_split('we@@@ty;rer@@2hjjj', ';');
```

---

Since Postgres 14

```
 select unnest(string_to_array(inputstr,delimeter));
```

can be simplified to

```
select string_to_table(inputstr,delimeter);
```

Comment: for your code out put getting like qww@@@qww,sdsd@@@sddd for me out should get ',' that should be separate

Comment: I don't understand what you really want. You state you want to "split" the values into an array. Yet your question shows an output where the delimiter is simply replaced with blanks, and now you want to replace the delimiter with a comma? Please make up your mind, and edit your question to **clearly** state what you want to achieve.

Comment: i want to store output in array but in comma should not come in between

Comment: "*i want to store output in array*" - the functions in my answer are **exactly** doing that.

Comment: yes sir your function storing output in array but in-between am getting comma i want output should be stored in different rows not in same row

Comment: So you want one row for each element after splitting up the input? That's again something different. An array is a **single** value not multiple rows. And your question does not show an expected output with multiple rows.

Comment: yes  is it possible to do using "unnest"